# Find first non blank cell in column with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

In an Excel table, how do I find the first cell containing data?

Comment: are you absolutely sure that you want it in VB.NET and not actually in VBA?

Comment: You can add an Excel component reference to your application and use VB.NET to manipulate the Excel sheet, just loop through each cell until you find a non-blank cell. This is if you really want to use .NET for this.

Comment: yes i 'm sure i want it in vb.net

Comment: just i want to find the first cell  no empty in excel file using vb.net

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d7061c8e-7132-42a9-b1fa-a8ca2fde8d9d/find-first-empty-cell-and-set-value)

you can also use

```
    If xlDataSheet.Cells(1, iCurrDataColumn).value Is Nothing Then 
    '.... do something 
    else
    '.....do something
```

Comment: hi !! i have many error with this code 
Error 3 'xlvalues' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.