# detection of the first full cell in an excel sheet with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I want to find the first cell containing data. 
I use this code but it doesn't work. 
I get an error in 'selection'.

```
Range("A1:BN1").Select
y = Selection.Find("*", After:=Range(Selection(1, 1).Address), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
```

**From the OP's comments:**

I tyr *[sic]* this

```
With xlWorkSheet
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row
    lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToRight).Column
End With
```

Comment: Re-post of [Find first non blank cell in column with vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915096/find-first-non-blank-cell-in-column-with-vb-net)

Comment: Exactly what error do you get?

Comment: can you give me a code with vb.net

Answer (score 0):

The first cell in Column A that contains data (i.e. is not blank) can be found with

```
Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)
```

Comment: It seems that the OP is looking for the first value in the first row, not column. Additionally, if A1 is not blank there is a good chance that that code will find the last, not the first.

Comment: Good points both.  To look right instead of down, substitute xlRight instead of xlDown.  I'd use an If-Then-Else to handle the case where A1 contains data; if A1 does NOT contain data then use the End(xlRight).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all you want is a number representing the column index with the first value in row 1. If you want the first, you have to look to the next one after the last. If you look for the next one after `Selection(1, 1)` then you are going to get the second if `Selection(1, 1)` is not blank.

```
Dim y As Long '◄ note: a long, not a range
With Range("A1:BN1")
    y = .Find("*", After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
End With
Debug.Print y
```

That is the (better) way to get the column index number without selection. If you feel that must keep using `Selection` then your code would be closer to the following.

```
Dim y As Long
Range("A1:BN1").Select
y = Selection.Find("*", After:=Selection(Selection.Rows.Count, Selection.Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlValues).Column
Debug.Print y
```

You were getting the selection's address and converting that back to a range object with `Range(...)` so I cut a couple of operations out of that process.

**Addendum:**

Your comments indicate that you want either the cell or the entire column with the first value in row 1. If that is the case, then this is more appropriate.

```
Dim y As Range '◄ note: now a range
With Range("A1:BN1")
    Set y = .Find("*", After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlValues)  '◄ note no .Column at the end
End With
Debug.Print y.Address
Debug.Print y.EntireColumn.Address
```

Comment: i have an error in "with range ("A1:Z10") "La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.

Comment: @tamara - That's because your `.Find` is returning the cell column number, not the cell as a range object. See my addendum for an alternate solution.

Comment: @tamara - If there are still Range Parent problems, you will have to supply enough VB.Net code to resolve them. The proffered solution above is meant to fix your problem as stated, not rewrite your code into a different language with unknown variables.

Comment: i tyr this   With xlWorkSheet
            lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row
            lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToRight).Column
        End With

Comment: @tamara - At first glance, you should be starting at the bottom and going up, not down. Similarly, you are starting at the extreme right and looking right. Use `xlUp` and `xlToLeft`. The operation you are describing here does not work the same way as `.Find`. Don't try to mash-up the two.